# Diff HEAD and merge-branch against parent for merge conflicts in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-diff

For better or worse, I regularly encounter in my Git workflow scenarios with fairly large merge conflicts. I find the best way to resolve these is typically to get the diffs of a) the HEAD branch against the parent branch, and b) the merge-branch against the parent branch, in order to manually inspect the changes and incorporate bits of both. However, Git and Visual Studio Code does not at all make this easy. Is there any solution, ideally specifically for VS Code, that allows me to inspect these two diffs for each merge conflict?

Comment: Other editors have really effective merge tools. If nobody's implemented one for VS Code, either nobody's bothered or it's not possible.  Looking at its extension docs, it's possible, kinda, but it's not an api I'd like working with, it doesn't surprise me.

Comment: @jthill I suspect you might be right; thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2):

`git mergetool` is what Git provides as a building block here.  It is by no means perfect, but it provides the three key inputs: the merge tool that `git mergetool` runs, which you may construct yourself, gets as its arguments your own expansion(s) of these variables that hold file names:

```
$BASE
$LOCAL
$REMOTE
$MERGED
$BACKUP
```

Not all files will always be present.  In particular, `$BACKUP` is omitted if you tell `git mergetool` that it can trust the merge tool's exit status.  Tools should generally ignore the `$BACKUP` variable, but see below.

Your tool's job is to produce, in `$MERGED`, the correct resolved file data.  You may read the text of the merge base input from `$BASE`.  The `HEAD` or `--ours` version of the file is in `$LOCAL`, and the other or `--theirs` version of the file is in `$REMOTE`.  Your tool can use any code you can think of and write, including running `diff` commands from `$BASE` to `$LOCAL` and/or from `$BASE` to `$REMOTE`, if you wish.

#### How this all works

Note that `git mergetool` operates on *one file at a time*.  That is, `git merge` has already made its best attempt at doing the merge on its own.  This attempt has failed (otherwise you would not be running `git mergetool`).

At `git merge` time, Git read (past tense) three sets of files from three commits:

- a merge base commit, containing whatever files are in that snapshot;
- an "ours" commit (`HEAD`), containing whatever files—or in some cases, such as with `git stash apply`, the files in the working tree were copied into the index and those were used as the "ours" commit; and
- a "theirs" commit (the other commit, `--theirs` or "remote" here).

Let's assume for illustration that in the merge base commit we had a file `foo.txt`, in the `--ours` commit we had `foo.txt`, and in the other commit we had `foo.txt`, and there was a merge conflict at lines 100–120 or so, plus non-conflicting changes on earlier and later lines.

Because Git did its best to combine our changes with their changes, there is a `foo.txt` file in the working tree right now that contains Git's attempt.  This has Git's decision as to what the right result was for the earlier and later lines, and, in place of the original lines 100–120 or so, conflict markers and the "ours" and "theirs" sections of the corresponding files (plus the corresponding "base" section if using `diff3` or the new `zdiff3` format).

Because Git *failed* to *fully resolve* the file, though, Git's *index* now contains all three input files: `:1:foo.txt` has the base version, `:2:foo.txt` has the `--ours` version, and `:3:foo.txt` has the `--theirs` version in it.  The `git mergetool` command copies these three versions of `foo.txt` *out* of the index—the index copies are in Git's internal read-only compressed-and-de-duplicated format, unreadable by anything other than Git itself—into ordinary files with peculiar temp-file names.

Now that these four versions of the file exist (base, local, "remote"/theirs, and merged), the `git mergetool` command sets up four shell variables, `$BASE`, `$LOCAL`, `$REMOTE`, and `$MERGED` to hold the four file *names* that hold these contents.  Since `$MERGED` is the simple file name (`foo.txt`) it doesn't have any funny dots or pids or `/tmp` or whatever squeezed into its name, but your program should just use `$MERGED` to find the file's name.  Again, this is where your program—your merge tool—should write its final result.

If you *don't* tell Git to trust your command's exit status, Git will copy the initial (pre-tool-run) copy of `$MERGED` to a temporary file named `$BACKUP`.  After your tool exits, regardless of its exit code, Git will compare the contents in `$BACKUP` against the contents in `$MERGED`.  If the two files *match*, Git will assume the tool failed and the file is not resolved yet.  If the two files *differ*, Git will assume the tool *succeeded* and the file is resolved correctly.

If you *do* tell Git to trust your command's exit status, Git doesn't bother with this, and just looks for zero (succeeded) or nonzero (failed) as the exit status.

In either case, having run your command to completion, Git now uses the success/failure indicator to decide whether to run `git add` on `$MERGED`.  If Git believes the tool has succeeded, `git mergetool` will run the `git add` command, which will mark the file resolved (knocking out the three nonzero-stage index entries and putting in a single stage-zero entry).  If Git believes the tool has failed, `git mergetool` does nothing, leaving the three nonzero-stage index entries that mark the file as unresolved, enabling later resolution and keeping the three inputs available.

The `mergetool` code then cleans up its temporary files, and goes on to the next unresolved file.  It simply iterates through all unresolved files, one at a time, running your chosen merge tool as described above.  Or, you can run `git mergetool f1.ext f2.ext` to limit it to resolving just those two files, for instance.

Since you can provide a shell script, binary executable, or whatever you like *as* the merge tool, you can get it to behave any way you like: it's just a [Small Matter of Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_matter_of_programming).  The painful part here is that it's always run one file at a time, so it never gets a "global view" of the diffs across all files.  (Also, for tree-level conflicts, such as rename/rename or modify/delete, `git mergetool` falls back on rather primitive prompting.)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed background on on merge conflicts and `git mergetool`. It's good to know, though I'm not sure it answers the question directly, in particular with regards to VS Code tools.